# Why isn't there a millisecond flag for to_stream and from_stream formatting in HowardHinnant's date.h library

Tags: c++, date, time, c++-chrono

I am using HowardHinnant date.h to format a filename which must include the time to millisecond accuracy n the form  HH-MM-SS-ms

i.e

10-23-44-564

Currently to do this I have to cast the time_point to millisecond accuracy and use the %S flag e.g.

```
 "%H-%M-%S"
```

The fractional period '.' must then be changed to a hyphen.

This all seems rather clumsy and leads me to believe I am over-thinking this.

Can anyone set me straight ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's not a great way to do this.  However one can create a `facet` that supplies `-` as the decimal point character and use that in the `format` call like this:

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

class punct_facet: public std::numpunct<char>
{
protected:
    char do_decimal_point() const override { return '-'; }
};

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    cout << format(locale{locale{}, new punct_facet},
                   "%H-%M-%S", 15h + 34min + 9s + 123ms) << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
15-34-09-123
```

And here's another way to work it:

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    auto d = 15h + 34min + 9s + 23ms;
    auto s = floor<seconds>(d);
    cout << format("%H-%M-%S-", s) << setfill('0') << setw(3) << (d-s).count() << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
15-34-09-023
```

Comment: Thanks Howard, are there any plans to introduce a millisecond formatting flag ?

Comment: Sorry, not at this time.  This library has been voted into the draft C++ 20 spec, and we're feature complete at this time for C++20.  Just trying to fix bugs and hold things steady for now.